# How to find the class which actually holds the element in java

Tags: java, oop

Say I have two classes

```
class parentClass{
   String myElement;
}
class childClass extends parentClass{
   String notMyElemtent;
}
```

Now say there is an object of class childClass. Is there a way programatically tell that myElement in that object belongs to parentClass originally??

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.  What code would you like to be able to write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with reflection. Use obj.getClass().getField("myElement") to get Field object, representing your field.
Now you can use [getDeclaringClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Member.html#getDeclaringClass%28%29) method of [Member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Member.html) interface to get class or interface actually declaring this member. So do something like this

```
childClass obj = new childClass();
Field field = obj.getClass().getField("myElement");
if (field.getDeclaringClass().equals(parentClass.class)) {
    // do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation or description to your code. Anyways +1 because you're new and trying to help!

Comment: Good approach, but two remarks: 1. `getField()` is a method of class - you need to do `obj.getClass().getField()`. 2. `getField()` only returns **public** fields (this is different from using `getDeclaredFields()`) - when using the original code from the question, you do not get the fields at all since they have default protection.

Comment: 1. Of course, this is my mistake, I'll fix it. 2. `getDeclaredFields()` returns only fields, declared by exactly this class. So if we call `childClass.class.getDeclaredFields()`, we won't get "myElement".

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to tell that myElement in that object belongs to parentClass originally?

Yes, you can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to examine the fields of the super class:

- Use [Class.getSuperClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29) to get the super class
- Then, use

  - [Class.getDeclaredFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) on the returned class from the above call to get a list of all fields declared by the super class
  - [Class.getDeclaredField(String fieldName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29) to directly check the existence of a given field

In code, this could look like:

```
public static boolean belongsToParent(Object o, String fieldName) {
   Class<?> sc = o.getClass().getSuperclass();
   boolean result = true;
   try {
      sc.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
   } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      result = false;
   }
   return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   childClass cc = new childClass();

   System.out.println("myElement belongs to parentClass: " + 
                      belongsToParent(cc,  "myElement"));
   System.out.println("notMyElemtent belongs to parentClass: " + 
                      belongsToParent(cc,  "notMyElemtent"));
}
```

Output:

```
myElement belongs to parentClass: true
notMyElemtent belongs to parentClass: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, use [`getDeclaredField(name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29) of a class, and if its not there, try looking at its super class and so on. Works for multiple levels of inheritance:

```
Class<?> clazz = childClass.class;
do {
    try {
        Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        //there it is! print the name of the super class that holds the field
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
} while (clazz != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Child child = new Child();
        System.out.println(getDeclaringClass(child.getClass(), "value"));

    }

    public static String getDeclaringClass(Class<?> clazz, String name) {
        try {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(name);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            if(clazz.getSuperclass() != null){
                return getDeclaringClass(clazz.getSuperclass(), name);              
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }

        return clazz.getName();
    }
}

class Parent {
    String value = "something";

}

class Child extends Parent {

}
```